# Azure DnsManagementClient ListAllByDnsZone vs ListByDnsZone

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk, azure-dns

Can someone explain the difference between **ListAllByDnsZone** vs **ListByDnsZone** methods in Azure .NET SDK **DnsManagementClient** RecordSets operations

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dns/record-sets/list-all-by-dns-zone

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dns/record-sets/list-by-dns-zone

Comment: It seems documentation is yet to be updated. [DNS spec contains two methods that perform the same action and has same description.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/2853)